# How do I edit references in MonoDevelop?

Tags: c#, reference, monodevelop

I need to add a Unity reference (and more) for a C# plugin. Researching this question, people wrote to go to "Project -> Edit References" or to right-click the "References" item in the directory. However, the "Edit References" tab is grayed out, if it's there at all. Additionally, there is no "References" item or folder. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

In the screenshots you have created a Shared Project. This project is basically a set of files and does not have the concept of references. A shared project is meant to be referenced by one or more other projects and allows a simple way to share multiple files across these projects without having to use file linking.

For a Unity plugin I would expect you would need to create a C# library project which is available under Other - .NET - Library.

[image: New project dialog]

Comment: Thanks! I created a Shared Project because the tutorial I was using didn't mention which one I should use.

Answer (score 0):

Underneath your game's name on the left bar which says `Solution`, there should be a subheading that says `Assembly-CSharp`. Select that and then try and select `Project -> Edit References` again.

**EDIT 2** Shared projects cannot add references, as said [in the documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/shared_projects/). As said as the person underneath, the best way is not to use a shared project but a library project instead.

Comment: The only nodes on the left bar are the solution, the project, and one class.

Comment: @heptagon I edited the answer - just select the project node.

Comment: If I select the project node, there is no Edit References button in the Project tab. If I select the solution node or the class node, the Edit References button is grayed out.

Comment: @heptagon What version of Unity are you using? I am currently trying to replicate it

Comment: I don't have Unity installed right now, but my problem is that I can't edit/add references at all. My Unity version doesn't matter if I can't even access it. Besides, I'm trying to extend a Unity game, not use Unity directly.